# VB-NET Clicar em um elemento(clicar em si próprio) enabled false, para ficar enabled true

Tags: vb.net

Olá.

Minha dúvida é em VB-NET

Como posso deixar Enabled true, uma imagem que está Enabled false, clicando nela própria. É possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, você pode fazer isso manipulando via javascript, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```js
 function troca()
 {
  
  document.getElementById("imagem").style.display = 'none';
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p>Click na imagem...</p>

 <img id="imagem" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PrjrEZcQM7o/maxresdefault.jpg" onclick="troca()" style="display: normal" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi como uma resposta de JavaScript pode responder uma pergunta de Visual Basic.

Comment: Te respondi em javascript porque é bem melhor o sistema manipular o campo no cliente do quê ir no servidor pra fazer isso... Mas se você quiser o código do VB .NET eu coloco....